# Como adicionar tabs na minha bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap, modal

Estou utilizando a biblioteca bootstrap do twitter versão 4.0
Consegui criar uma janela modal porém gostaria de adicionar abas nela, encontrei alguns códigos mas não consegui implementar eles..

Segue como estou tentando:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Adicionar Ação</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home Tab</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile Tab</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Content</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile Content</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

A chamada do meu model é feita assim:

$('#myModal').modal('show');

Alguém sabe como eu posso adicionar abas na minha modal, ou conhece algum tutorial que eu possa estudar? 
Obrigado.

---

Edit, segue uma imagem do que preciso: s.bootply.com/render/QKuuimkQTC
Quero colocar as abas dentro da minha modal como no exemplo, porém no momento ela está ficando assim: prntscr.com/djsekx

Comment: Olhe, a versão 4 ainda não é estável. Pode não ter todas as funcionalidades prontas. Mas essas `TABS` devem ser acessíveis enquanto o `MODAL` estiver aberto, certo?

Comment: Na verdade eu quero as tabs dentro da modal, como nesse exemplo:
http://s.bootply.com/render/QKuuimkQTC

Comment: Isso mesmo. Entendi. Isso é `JQuery`. Acho até que tenho um modelo pronto aqui que já usei... Já tentou passar o conteúdo das `divs` `id="home"` e `id="profile"` com um `include`?

Comment: Não tenho nada de conteúdo ainda, o meu problema é que as abas nem aparecem, minha modal fica assim: http://prntscr.com/djsekx

Comment: Ah... Certo. A falha é na exibição...

Comment: Isto, desculpe não ser claro.. Vou fazer um edit na pergunta..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema.. No fim eu tinha um CSS antigo que setava estilo no UL, eu não lembrava que esse CSS existia..

Desculpem pelo erro, agora está aparecendo ;) obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando a versão 4.* com marcação de versão 3.*. Usei a marcação padrão da versão 4 extraída [daqui](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tab) e funcionou perfeitamente:

```
<!-- myModal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Adicionar Ação</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
  })
</script>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- myModal -->
```

Atenção ao que está dentro da `div` `<div class="modal-body">`.

Ah, também fiz a inclusão das bibliotecas usando o `CDN`: [referência](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#bootstrap-cdn), mas baixar tudo e incluir dá no mesmo, vc só precisa ter certeza de ter baixado os arquivos certos.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou.. Continua ficando assim: http://prntscr.com/dk3b8u
Vou partir da ideia de que a estrutura está certa agora, porém o CSS está da maneira que baixei, agora então só pode ser js.. :/

Comment: Olha, essa falha não tem relação com o comportamento, então não pode ser `javascript`. **Mostre aqui a maneira como vc está incluindo a biblioteca**, pode ser isso. Preste atenção à ordem de inclusão da biblioteca e siga o modelo apresentado pelo desenvolvedor: [exemplo](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template). Inclua o `bootstrap.min.css` antes de qualquer outra folha de estilos que vc esteja usando.

Comment: Encontrei o problema.. Segue a resposta que publiquei ;) obrigado por toda a ajuda.

Comment: Marque sua resposta, não deixe a pergunta sem resolução ;)

Comment: Sim, mas pra marcar minha própria resposta o stackO só libera amanhã.. hehe, amanhã marco ;) valeu

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o que precisa, colocar abas com conteudo, no caso, TABS. Você precisa colocar algo mais ou menos assim dentro de modal-body:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Você pode conferir pelo link: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: Eu quero fazer isso dentro da minha modal, como segue:
http://s.bootply.com/render/QKuuimkQTC

Comment: qual erro aparece quando vc usa um inspect element?

Comment: Desculpe Rubens, não entendi.. Não estou tendo nenhum erro apenas minhas abas não aparecem, segue como está no momento: prntscr.com/djsekx

Comment: Sim, mas preciso saber que tipo de erro aparece de java script para não funcionar a tabs, vc usa firebug? Você pode dar um inspect element na página para ver quais erros de js aparece

Comment: O problema não é `javascript`...

Comment: Tinha esquecido de verificar os erros da página pelo inspect, segue uma imagem do erro que aparece para mim.. Esse erro acontece no momento que abro minha page, antes de abrir a janela modal..

http://prntscr.com/djsnfv

Comment: Acredito que não seja JS mesmo, acho que é algo com o CSS ou a minha estrutura HTML..

Comment: Se não tiver nenhum erro de JS (que eu acho difícil) ou de carregamento de biblioteca, o problema pode ser CSS .. tenta carregar as bibliotecas novamente.. Ou usar uma versão anterior do bootstrap para testar.